# Swipe to Delete Section Header in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on extended data and a `UITableView`. I am able to use swipe to edit and delete functions. I am wondering if it is possible to swipe and delete only section headers. If yes, how?

Comment: no its not possible!!!! section headers will be removed when there are no rows!!!

Comment: That second part is not entirely true.  Section headers are removed when you don't return one from the delegate/datasource method.  It's perfectly possible to have a header for an otherwise empty section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve.
But if you want to have a swipe delete for a section header, the answer is, you can do it, but it requires some kind of programming. Essentially, you had to add a „section header delete button“ as a subview to the table views content view.
I suggest reading Ray Wenderlichs tutorial „[How To Make A Swipeable Table View Cell With Actions – Without Going Nuts With Scroll Views](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views)“. This demonstrates how you can add swipe gestures to a table view cell.
However the same techniques (e.g. controlling the position within the scroll view) can be applied to a section views header.