# Delete and reorder sections in tableview - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, sections

I'd like to make it so that I can reorder a section in the app and also delete the section by swiping left on the section header (not on the row). Currently I have managed to delete and reorder the row however this is not what I want. I have looked into the documentation on the Apple website and noticed that there is a function (move section) and (delete section), however I do not know how to implement these functions in my code and can find no examples on the Internet on how to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

[Swipe left to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbPyd.png).

["Edit"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX5nP.png)

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var data = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBAction func editAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.tableView.isEditing = !self.tableView.isEditing
        switch tableView.isEditing {
        case true:
            editButton.title = "Done"
        default:
            editButton.title = "Edit"
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        data = ["Phone", "Pen", "Pencil"]

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! TitleTableViewCell

        cell.titleLabel.text = data[section]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
        {
            data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let movedObjTemp = data[sourceIndexPath.row]
        data.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        data.insert(movedObjTemp, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    }

}
```

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612040/swipe-to-delete-section-header-in-uitableview

Comment: Thank you, I have seen this question before but I didn't know if there has been any updates.

Comment: The linked Wenderlich tutorial describes how to create a *swipe-able* custom cell.